# Reinitialize tabulator on same DOM element with new data and different column configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, tabulator

I am working with tabulator (jQuery plugin). I want to re-initialized the tabulator on same div element with different column config and data dynamically. Below is the sample div and script that I am using. I feel that, tabulator not allow to change the column configuration once its render.

```
$("#sample_div").tabulator(tabulator_display_config);

//initialize and apply tabulator
$("#sample_div").tabulator("setData", table_data.Data);

//load data into the table
```

Comment: @jmattheis most of time while editing , character limits is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redraw the tabulator after the new initialization

```
$("#sample_div").tabulator("setData", table_data.Data);
$("#sample_div").tabulator("redraw", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It refresh the data but doesn't update the columns. And if I use setColumn function, it will disturb the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I use the destroy function and reinitialize tabulator. It works for me.

```
$("#sample_div").tabulator("destroy");
$("#sample_div").tabulator(tabulator_display_config);
$("#sample_div").tabulator("setData", table_data.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change your column configuration and keep your sorting you could get your current sorting using the `getSorters` function before updating the columns and data and then resorting:

```
var sort = $("#sample_div").tabulator("getSorters");

$("#sample_div").tabulator(tabulator_display_config);
$("#sample_div").tabulator("setData", table_data.Data);
$("#sample_div").tabulator("setSort ", sort);
```